# Correct way of saying "errands to run"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, american-english

Which is the correct way to tell someone that I have errands to run?

Are all of these fine to say in person and in an email?

> I got some errands to run

or is it

> I have errands to run

or

> I need to run errands

Comment: Yes, they are all fine in informal English. There are also many other ways to say that, too numerous to list here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either the second or third; the first would only be good grammar if you mean that you were given some errands to run. ("I got some errands to run when I checked in with the boss").

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would be, "I've got some errands to run."